# Numbering format in IET BST

Tags: bibliographies

I would like to modify [IET.BST](https://www.codepile.net/pile/XYeKqPLp) to achieve a custom numbering format of the bibliography items.
Currently it looks like the picture below:

[image]

And I want it to be like to one below (numbers in brackets).

[image]

The working example can be found in [here](https://filebin.net/9ie5jxaylfd0id21)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. I am unable to reproduce the "look" shown  in the upper screenshot of your posting, using just the (very limited) information you've provided so far. Do please tell us if you use a citation management package and, if the answer is "yes", which one it is.

Comment: Thank you @Mico I am using IET's latex template. For the bibliography, I am inserting \bibliographystyle{iet} to tell Latex that I want iet.bst to be used as style. I use \bibliography{myrefs} to point to myrefs.bib which contains all my references in Bib format. Then inside the document text, I am calling each reference using it's id, e.g. \cite{reference_1}.

Comment: Is "IET's latex template" available online somewhere?

Comment: @Mico yes it is, I got it from overleaf https://tinyurl.com/yahc93yc

Comment: Sorry, I don't have a working Overleaf account. Have you contacted the Overleaf helpdesk? I hear their LaTeX support staff are very good.

Comment: I'll zip a working version, upload it and share the link

Comment: @Mico I uploaded the working example, it can be accessed from https://filebin.net/9ie5jxaylfd0id21

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am posting the solution in case others have same issue!

The solution is to simply open cta-author.cls and replace

```
\renewcommand\bibnumfmt[1]{{#1}}
```

with

```
\renewcommand\bibnumfmt[1]{{[#1]}}
```

Shout out to Batuhan Gundogdu who posted the solution on [Researchgate](https://www.researchgate.net/post/Which_bibliography_style_is_to_use_for_IET_journals_IET_Image_processing)